# Is it possible to modify a function of an open source API? I need to make a function more efficient or find a way around

Tags: c++, api, opencv, camera, shared-libraries

I am using the C++ API to control a camera and combine opencv functions on it (RaspiCamCV).

library is shared here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/? & https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam

official website is here: http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40

The camera itself is capable of shooting 90 frames per second on video mode. By using threads for parallel processing, I need to be doing some processing on every frame, as fast as possible.

I am using the code at the end to measure fps of continuous camera shots (not a video capture). The problem is, grab function below starts camera sensor, captures image and stops every time it is called (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=107885). This is extremely inefficient and ends up with ~30fps instead of 90.

How is it possible to obtain 90 frames per second in real time? Can I find a way around this? For example where can I find the source code for grab in this library, to create three functions instead, such as startSensor, grabFast (in the loop), stopSensor to make this API efficient?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <raspicam/raspicam_cv.h>
using namespace std; 

int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {

    time_t timer_begin,timer_end;
    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    cv::Mat image;
    int nCount=100;
    //set camera params
    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
    Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  640 );
    Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480 );
    //Open camera
    cout<<"Opening Camera..."<<endl;
    if (!Camera.open()) {cerr<<"Error opening the camera"<<endl;return -1;}
    //Start capture
    cout<<"Capturing "<<nCount<<" frames ...."<<endl;
    time ( &timer_begin );
    for ( int i=0; i<nCount; i++ ) {
        Camera.grab();
        Camera.retrieve ( image);
        if ( i%5==0 )  cout<<"\r captured "<<i<<" images"<<std::flush;
    }
    cout<<"Stop camera..."<<endl;
    Camera.release();
    //show time statistics
    time ( &timer_end ); /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */
    double secondsElapsed = difftime ( timer_end,timer_begin );
    cout<< secondsElapsed<<" seconds for "<< nCount<<"  frames : FPS = "<<  ( float ) ( ( float ) ( nCount ) /secondsElapsed ) <<endl;
    //save image 
    cv::imwrite("raspicam_cv_image.jpg",image);
    cout<<"Image saved at raspicam_cv_image.jpg"<<endl;
}
```

**edit years later following up on `yoGGie ツ`'s comment:**
I dont remember exactly how but I got it to work with 90fps eventually, but due to low exposure everything was way too dark to be useful. I think 90fps was available for only gray mode and some resolutions. so you might first find the phrase fps in config files of the library, start changing settings, rebuild it and test it. I guess that was how I ended up figuring this out and not using it anyway